# Не могу удалить таблицу Mysql

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Мне нужно обновить таблицу, но DROP TABLE выдает следующее:

```
#1451 - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

Причем не понятно какой ключ мешает удалению - никакой дополнительной информации не выводится. В чем может быть дело?

Comment: сначала удалите дочерний записи, связанные с родительской таблицей ограничением таблицы (constraint ), либо удалите ограничение внешнего ключа (foreign key), то тогда целостность базы не гарантируется.

Comment: Запрос `show create table ...` тоже ничего не показал?

Comment: @Jean-Claude, так в том что и дело что мне хотелось бы узнать какие таблицы связаны с этой. Как их можно посмотреть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего на эту таблицу ссылается какая-то другая. по аналогии с ответом с en SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4004205/mysql-show-constraints-on-tables-command

можно составить запрос:

```
use INFORMATION_SCHEMA;

select TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME,CONSTRAINT_NAME,
REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME,REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME from KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
where TABLE_SCHEMA = "название базы данных" and REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = "название таблицы которую хотите удалить"
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно!